# VS2013 codedui not waiting for pageload to complete before searching for control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

We recently migrated our codedui project from VS2010 to VS2013. Everything was working fine in VS2010, but in 2013 playback jumps to search controls as even before the page loads properly.

---

`To understand this properly consider this scenarios:`

1. Launch browser with url "www.example.com"
2. Enter login
3. Enter password
4. click submit. [on clicking submit it navigates to user profile page]
5. Navigate to url "www.example.com/sometask";
6. Click some button on "sometask" page

---

Now in VS2013, just after clicking submit in step 4, Codedui executes the steps 5 and tries to navigate to "sometask" page even before the user profile page is loaded. So it tries to navigate to next page even before the login is validated.

So basically it doesn't wait for the previous operation to complete. Any solution to this problem? I am not looking for inserting WaitForControlReady() everywhere as it was working earlier in VS2010.

---

> **Edit 1 :** This is happening with `BrowserWindow.NavigateToUrl()` only. It doesn't wait for the previous page load to complete and
>   starts navigating even before the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're using the correct `Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel`.  In your situation, setting this property to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly` should be sufficient for your purposes.  [Here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitest.extension.waitforreadylevel.aspx) to the MSDN article on the enum.